# Text based game in Java

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, battle-simulation

To help with learning code in my class, I've been working on this text based game to keep myself coding (almost) every day. I have a class called `BasicUnit`, and in it I have methods to create a custom class. I use 2 methods for this, allowing the user to enter the information for the class. I'm just wondering if I can do this in a more simplified manner?

```
    public void buildCustomClass(int maxHP, int maxMP, int maxSP, int baseMeleeDmg, int baseSpellDmg, int baseAC, int baseSpeed) {

    this.maxHP = maxHP;
    this.maxMP = maxMP;
    this.maxSP = maxSP;
    this.baseMeleeDmg = baseMeleeDmg;
    this.baseSpellDmg = baseSpellDmg;
    this.baseAC = baseAC;
    this.baseSpeed = baseSpeed;
    lvl = 1;
    xp = 0;
    curHP = maxHP;
    curMP = maxMP;
    curSP = maxSP;

}

public void createCustomClass() {
    kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the information for your class: ");
    System.out.println("Enter HP: ");
    maxHP = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter MP: ");
    maxMP = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter SP: ");
    maxSP = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Base Melee Damage: ");
    baseMeleeDmg = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Base Spell Damage: ");
    baseSpellDmg = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter AC: ");
    baseAC = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Speed: ");
    baseSpeed = kb.nextInt();

    buildCustomClass(maxHP, maxMP, maxSP, baseMeleeDmg, baseSpellDmg, baseAC, baseSpeed);
}
```

Comment: Could you include the actual class this is in? These 2 methods are used to initialise a certain class but you're not really creating one. Without the surrounding code it's hard to explain the difference.

Comment: This looks like it could be a pretty good spot for the [Builder Pattern](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html). But, I would need to see more code to make a recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review and thanks for sharing your code!

## General issues

### Naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in programming. So always take your time to think carefully of your identifier names.

#### Naming Conventions

It looks like you already know the 
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

#### Avoid abbreviations

In your code you use some abbreviations such as  `maxSP` and `baseMeleeDmg`.
Although this abbreviation makes sense to you (now) anyone reading your code being not familiar with the problem (like me) has a hard time finding out what this means.

If you do this to save typing work: remember that you way more often read your code than actually typing something. Also for Java you have good IDE support with code completion so that you most likely type a long identifier only once and later on select it from the IDEs code completion proposals.

---

> The other identifiers make perfect sense to me. [because of context] – AJD

Context looks like your friend but in fact it is your enemy.

There are two reasons:

1. Context depends on *knowlegde* and *experience*. But different persons have different knowlegde and experience, so for one it might be easy to remember the context and for another it might be hard. Also your own knowledge and experiences change over time so you might find it hard to remember the context of any given code snipped you wrote when you come back to it in 3 in years or even 3 moth.

   The point is that in any case you need (more or less) *time* to bring the context back to you brain.
   But the only thing that you usually don't have when you do programming as a business ist time. So anything that makes you faster in understanding the code is a money worth benefit. And not needing to remember any context is such a time saver.
2. You may argue that we have a very simple promblem with an easy and common context. Thats true.
   But:

   - Real life projects usually have higher complexity and less eays to remember contexts. The point here is:
     At which point is your context so complext that you switch from "acronym naming" to "verbose nameing"?

     Again this point changes with you knowledge and your experience wich may lead to code that others have a hard time to understand.

     The much better way to deal with it is to *always* white your code in a way that the dumbest person you know may be able to understand it. And this includes not to use akronyms in your identifiers that *might* need context to understand.
   - This is a *training* project. When you train a physical skill like Highjumping you start with a very low bar that you can easily pass even not using the *flop* technique just to have a safe environment.

     Same is here: The problem may be simple enough to be understood having the acronymed identifiers, but for the sake of training you should avoid acronyms.

#### Avoid misleading naming

Both of your method names are misleading: They claim to *create* and *build* something but in reality neither one is creating or building anything.

One method is doing *user interaction* and the other is *configuring* the object.

The names of the methods should reflect that.

#### Add units to identifiers for physical values

Physical values do mean nothing without a *unit*. This is a special case of the *context problem* mentioned above.  The most famous example is the fail of the two space missions *Mars Climate Orbiter* and *Mars Polar Lander*. The Flight control software was build by NASA and worked with *metric* measurement (i.e. `meters`, `meters per second` or `newton seconds`) while the engine (and their driver software) has been build by *Lockheed Martin* which use *imperial* units (i.e. `feet`, `feet per minute` or `Pound-force second`).

The point is: not having *units* of physical values in your identifiers forces you to *think* if there is a problem or not:

```
double acceleration = flightManagement.calculateAcceleration();
engine.accelerate(acceleration);
```

But usually you don't quesion it unless you have a reason...

Having the units in the identifier names the problem becomes obvious:

```
double meterPerSquareSeconds = 
          flightManagement.calculateAccelerationInMeterPerSquareSecond();
engine.accelerateByFeedPerSquareMinute(
          meterPerSquareSeconds); // oops
```

And we have the same argument again: your particular code is so easy and so small that we don't need the overhead.
But then: How do you decide at which point the overhead is needed? And again it depends on knowledge and experience which still are different among people...

## Flawed implementation

Both methods using the *same* member variables. 
E.g. you variable   `maxSP`: in `createCustomClass()` you assign it the result of `kb.nextInt()`. Then you pass this value as parameter to `buildCustomClass()` where you again assign the parameter value  again  to the *same*  member variable.

Beside this being useless it may lead to confusing bugs later.

## keep same level of abstraction

Methods should either do "primitive" opeerations or call other methods, not both at the same time.

At the end of your method `createCustomClass()` you call the other method (`buildCustomClass()`). The better way to do this is to extract the code before the call to `buildCustomClass()` in a separate (private) method:

```
public void createCustomClass() {
    aquireDataFromUser();
    buildCustomClass(
          maxHP, 
          maxMP, 
          maxSP, 
          baseMeleeDmg, 
          baseSpellDmg, 
          baseAC, 
          baseSpeed);
}

private void aquireDataFromUser() {
    kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the information for your class: ");
    System.out.println("Enter HP: ");
    maxHP = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter MP: ");
    maxMP = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter SP: ");
    maxSP = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Base Melee Damage: ");
    baseMeleeDmg = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Base Spell Damage: ");
    baseSpellDmg = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter AC: ");
    baseAC = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Speed: ");
    baseSpeed = kb.nextInt();
}
```

Beside making `createCustomClass()` shorter it makes the useless reassingment of the member variables obvious.

Comment: With "Naming", the only name I pick fault with is "kb", which I assume means "keyboard" - so that name could be better. The other identifiers make perfect sense to me.

Comment: @AJD *"The other identifiers make perfect sense to me."* - If this is your start into a programmers career keep in mind that you will have to collaborate with others. And the identifiers you choose must make "perfect sense" to your futur team mates too. Also: you asked for improvements. Accept them or not. There is no need to explain yourself...

Comment: Well, thank you kind sir. My start into programming was about ... umm 40 years ago. I recognise the context for those variable names, and they do make perfect sense - these terms are used in "real life" (if you know the context you would see the humour in that), so the variable names are reflecting common terminology. BTW, I am not the OP so I did not ask for the improvements, but I was providing you with a comment so you could look at your judgemental comment in part of your answer and provide a better answer.

Comment: @AJD So your argument is that cryptic identifier names are OK because of context? Well my experience in the programming business is only 20 years. But I for myself find it easier to work with  clear names without acronyms even if they are somewhat lengthly. And please keep in mind: modern languages (like java or even C) have virtually no limit for the length of identifiers, and actual monitors can show more than 80x25 characters,   Some progress happened here in the last 40 years... ;o)

Comment: my point is that they are not cryptic. You just can't see the full context yourself. Please don't project your ignorance (and I mean this politely - "Although this abbreviation makes sense to you (now) anyone reading your code being not familiar with the problem (like me) has a hard time finding out what this means.") . You are only seeing a small sliver of a larger world, anyone who is looking at this code for the purposes for which the code is meant will understand the context. As I said, this is common parlance in that context.

Comment: @AJD *"his is common parlance in that context"* And BTW this was the reason why two mars missions  failed (Mars Climate Orbiter and  Mars Polar Lander): some teams contributing software had their own context (metric vs imperial units). So yes: I think that identifiers should not have any acronyms and only short living local variables may be very common abbreviations.

Comment: I think the question to ask is "why?" Why would you use abbreviated names? The answer used to be simple. To save space and typing. But, with better monitors and autocomplete, those reasons have mostly gone by the way side. So, it is always good for a developer to be descriptive when naming things in these modern languages, whether or not the context is understood or will only be used by specific people that understand it. It's always good for a developer to code using descriptive naming; building good habits. There are exceptions, like JavaScript (size of files), but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Comments here getting a little off track. This is not the same as two countries confusing units of measurement. This is merely the difference between saying `maxHP` or `maxHitPoints` when everyone in this environment speaks "HP" anyway. So, according to the language used `maxHP` is not really an abbreviated name. My key point is that the answerer gave a vague section on Naming, pointed out a hint without any concrete reasoning or counterexamples behind it; and I think the reason behind this is that the answerer didn't understand the environment in which this code would be used.

Comment: .. this would be like me commenting on a bit of financial code and then discussing whether the variable should be named `average`, `mean` or `mode`. I know a bit about statistics, but not in the context of the code itself where those may have specific terms. Or how about project management code where a variable could be named "ACWP". It has unambiguous meaning in that context.

Comment: @AJD, you're saying the same stuff you said before. It's also about building good habits and making sure the code is maximally readable by all developers. Abbreviating variable names is frowned upon in order to create good habits. It absolutely should be `maxHitPoints`. This developer is asking for a code review. Someone that knows the language may not understand the context and not understand what `maxHP` means in this very question. So, the abbreviation would create confusion when asking for code review on a site like this. This question is an example of why descriptive naming is important.

Comment: In other words, you can't guarantee the person looking at the code is going to understand all of the abbreviations that someone in the specified role _should_ understand. They may be new, or reviewing code, or learning how things work. The abbreviations might be assumed to be universal in that role, but they aren't. In your example, what if one group uses EVA instead of `ACWP`? What if another doesn't use `EVA` at all and needs to look up that it means `Earned Value Analysis`, because they always just use `ACWP`?......

Comment: .....It isn't a perfect example, but as things get more complicated and differ between groups, the more problems with naming there will be. So, be descriptive in naming.

Comment: Thank you for addressing my comments - makes for a more complete answer.  In your example, acceleration should be `metersPerSecondPerSecond` or `metersPerSecondSecond` or `meterPerSecondSquared` for the same technical reasons as you have pointed out.

Comment: @adpro: Yes, full descriptive naming is a good habit but there are no absolutes. In this context, the user input is `System.out.println("Enter HP: ");`, so using `HP` in the variable is defendable (even if not optimal or a good habit). Good comments in the code can help the defendable position - even including a glossary of accepted terms! No absolutes and many ways to skin the cat.

Comment: @AJD *"Good comments in the code can help the defendable position"* No. Good comments are *ortogonal* and supportive to good naming. This is because comments should not repeat the code but explain *why* the code is like it is.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: "Good comments are ortogonal and supportive to good naming."  Agree. "This is because comments should not repeat the code but explain why the code is like it is." Agree.  So a comment within the class (or module or wherever the code is) like 'maxHP denotes the maximum hit points (& other reasons or context)` is another way of addressing the issue. `maxHP` or `maximumHitPoints`? There are always counter examples - you have provided some yourself (but probably don't realise it).

Comment: @TimothyTruckle but then, I never could do the High Jump :-)

Comment: @AJD, your comment of `maxHP denotes the maximum hit points` shows how silly it is to not use `maximumHitPoints`. Why add a comment that can be described in code? Comments become outdated. Also, the `acceleration` example is a good example of when to use a comment, but not a good example of when not to abbreviate in variable names. `acceleration` is not an abbreviation. If you used `accl` or something then that would be a similar example. You might include the type of acceleration in the variable name if it fits. Either way, abbreviations don't help, and not abbreviating isn't harmful.